# How can I programmatically add a contact?

Tags: android, emulation, android-contacts

I am trying to programmatically add a contact in Android. Here is my code:

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,"Google")
    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,"user1@gmail.com") .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValueBackReference(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,rawContactInsertIndex)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
    .build());


ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, phone)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE, phoneType)
    .build());


ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract
    .Data.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,rawContactInsertIndex)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA, email)
    .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.TYPE, emailType)
    .build());

try {
    getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence txt = "Contact " + name +" added successfully";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(ctx, txt, duration);
    toast.show();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Am I doing this correctly? How can I add an account name and account type?

**NOTE: I don't have any account created. Is it mandatory to have account in order to add a contact?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Contact API storing contact as an invisible contact: How to make it visible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387960/contact-api-storing-contact-as-a-invisible-contact-how-to-make-it-visible) check this i hope it will be useful!

there is no need of creating any account in the phone!... i think their is some default account to do that!