# how to display the phone contacts?

Tags: android, contacts

i am getting the phone no,mail, name from contacts and stored in side the 3array list, display the contacts.

the contacts are stored in side the array list sequentially.

if i store a contact contains phone no,name and with out mail id.

i want to store the mail id null in side the mails array list.

if any one has solution please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Main Activity how can retrieve data...

```
 public class AddressBook extends Activity
    {
    ListView lv1;
    String[] row,row1;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
//how can retrieve contact details ...................................................
    ContactList1.getContactEmails(this,emailContacts1);
    ContactList1.getContactNumbers(this,phoneContacts1);
    how can implemented the code.......................................
    }
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem? There's no rule against adding null objects to a list.

Comment: [one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192559/is-it-possible-to-selecte-multiple-contacts-from-contact-picker), [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726282/how-can-i-add-a-contact-in-android) and [three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387960/contact-api-storing-contact-as-a-invisible-contact-how-to-make-it-visible) hope these link may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following approach

Try to create a bean where you will store details and create an arraylist of that bean class

### AddressBook.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email;
import android.provider.ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class AddressBook extends Activity
{
ListView lv1;
String[] row,row1;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<ContactEmailBean> emailContacts1 = getContactEmails(this);
        ArrayList<ContactNumberBean> phoneContacts1 = getContactNumbers(this);


    }



    public ArrayList<ContactNumberBean> getContactNumbers(Context context) {
        String contactNumber = null;
        int contactNumberType = Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;
        String nameOfContact = null;
        ArrayList<ContactNumberBean> phoneContacts = new ArrayList<ContactNumberBean>();
            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                    nameOfContact = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    if (Integer
                            .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                        Cursor phones = cr
                                .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                        null,
                                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                                + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                        null);

                        while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                            contactNumber = phones.getString(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                            contactNumberType = phones.getInt(phones
                                    .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

                            phoneContacts
                                    .add(new ContactNumberBean(nameOfContact,
                                            contactNumber, contactNumberType));
                        }
                        phones.close();
                    }

                }
            }// end of contact name cursor
            cur.close();
    return phoneContacts;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * This method is responsible to get native contacts and corresponding email
     * id (ApplicationConstants.emailContacts)
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public ArrayList<ContactEmailBean> getContactEmails(Context context) {
        String emailIdOfContact = null;
        int emailType = Email.TYPE_WORK;
        String contactName = null;
        ArrayList<ContactEmailBean> emailContacts = new ArrayList<ContactEmailBean>();



            ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
            Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                    null, null, null);
            if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
                while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                    String id = cur.getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                    contactName = cur
                            .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    // Log.i(TAG,"....contact name....." +
                    // contactName);

                    cr.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                    + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                    Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                            Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                    while (emails.moveToNext()) {
                        emailIdOfContact = emails.getString(emails
                                .getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                        // Log.i(TAG,"...COntact Name ...."
                        // + contactName + "...contact Number..."
                        // + emailIdOfContact);
                        emailType = emails.getInt(emails
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                        emailContacts
                                .add(new ContactEmailBean(contactName,
                                        emailIdOfContact, emailType));

                    }
                    emails.close();

                }
            }// end of contact name cursor
            cur.close();

    return emailContacts;
    }
}
```

here Class B does not extends Activity.
But write the following method to gwt contacts and email id in class B

```
public static void getContactNumbers(Context context) {
    String contactNumber = null;
    int contactNumberType = Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;
    String nameOfContact = null;
    ArrayList<ContactNumberBean> phoneContacts = new ArrayList<ContactNumberBean>();
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                nameOfContact = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor phones = cr
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                    null);

                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        contactNumber = phones.getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                        contactNumberType = phones.getInt(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

                        phoneContacts
                                .add(new ContactNumberBean(nameOfContact,
                                        contactNumber, contactNumberType));
                    }
                    phones.close();
                }

            }
        }// end of contact name cursor
        cur.close();

}

/**
 * 
 * This method is responsible to get native contacts and corresponding email
 * id (ApplicationConstants.emailContacts)
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public static void getContactEmails(Context context) {
    String emailIdOfContact = null;
    int emailType = Email.TYPE_WORK;
    String contactName = null;
    ArrayList<ContactEmailBean> emailContacts = new ArrayList<ContactEmailBean>();



        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                contactName = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                // Log.i(TAG,"....contact name....." +
                // contactName);

                cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                while (emails.moveToNext()) {
                    emailIdOfContact = emails.getString(emails
                            .getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                    // Log.i(TAG,"...COntact Name ...."
                    // + contactName + "...contact Number..."
                    // + emailIdOfContact);
                    emailType = emails.getInt(emails
                            .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                    emailContacts
                            .add(new ContactEmailBean(contactName,
                                    emailIdOfContact, emailType));

                }
                emails.close();

            }
        }// end of contact name cursor
        cur.close();


}
```

Write two bean class

### EmailBean

```
public class ContactEmailBean {
        String emailType = null;
        String nameOfContact = null;

        String emailIdOfContact = null;

        public ContactEmailBean(String nameOfContact, String emailIdOfContact,
                int emailType) {
            switch (emailType) {
            case Email.TYPE_HOME:
                this.emailType = "HOME";
                // do something with the Home number here...
                break;
            case Email.TYPE_MOBILE:
                this.emailType = "MOBILE";
                // do something with the Mobile number here...
                break;
            case Email.TYPE_WORK:
                this.emailType = "WORK";
                // do something with the Work number here...
                break;

            default:
                this.emailType = "OTHER";
                break;
            }
            this.nameOfContact = nameOfContact;
            this.emailIdOfContact = emailIdOfContact;

        }

        public String getNameOfContact() {
            return this.nameOfContact;
        }

        public String getEmailType() {
            return this.emailType;
        }

        public String getEmailIdOfContact() {
            return this.emailIdOfContact;
        }
    }
```

### ContactNumberBean

```
public class ContactNumberBean {
        String phoneNumberType = null;
        String nameOfContact = null;
        String contactNumber = null;

        public ContactNumberBean(String nameOfContact, String contactNumber,
                int contactNumberType) {
            switch (contactNumberType) {
            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                this.phoneNumberType = "HOME";
                // do something with the Home number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                this.phoneNumberType = "MOBILE";
                // do something with the Mobile number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                this.phoneNumberType = "WORK";
                // do something with the Work number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE:
                this.phoneNumberType = "WORK";
                break;

            case Phone.TYPE_FAX_HOME:
                this.phoneNumberType = "FAX";
                break;
            default:
                this.phoneNumberType = "OTHER";
                break;
            }
            this.nameOfContact = nameOfContact;
            this.contactNumber = contactNumber;

        }

        public String getNameOfContact() {
            return this.nameOfContact;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumberType() {
            return this.phoneNumberType;
        }

        public String getContactNumber() {
            return this.contactNumber;
        }

}
```

Thanks
Deepak

Comment: did you try with the above approach? if yes what is the problem can you ellaborate so that i will try to help you because I have tested the above approach

Comment: how can retrieve data in main activity please forward some solution Class A extends Activity{

new ClassB(this);//how can implemented retrieve list functionality... 
}

Comment: i am edit my question adding main activity plaese see once deepak i am struck in more days

Comment: check my answer now. It wil work for you as I have done with implementation. If any issue come let me know

Comment: you can make a upvote or accept if my answer is working for you

Comment: my problem  is other contact details pass to class to activity i am getting contacts in ContactList1 class in main activity create instance of the class how get contact list